# Is there a way to Inset in the opposite direction (not Outset)?

Tags: modeling, faces, geometry

Is there an operation similar to inset that creates faces in the opposite direction? That is, instead of creating faces inwards, they create faces outwards?

A normal inset operation:
[image: A normal Inset operation:]
What I would like:
[image: What I would like:]

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work as you end up with incorrect corner ratios.
Consider what will happen with the corner in the centre of the image; they won't converge with a simple scale transformation.

Comment: The easiest workaround can be to scale whole model / relevant part of model and inset the desired loop after. This is known problem also of Solidify modifier which I don't think easy to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using the addon "[Offset edges](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges)".

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks, Omar!
The addon has some pretty neat features too which would be nice to see on the native Inset operation (I am referring to the angle options, which I think will prove very useful).

Comment: This really ought to be in the default toolset!

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution without extra add-ons or complex mesh tweaking.
Simply follow the steps as shown in the images.

[image: Select border edges!]
[image: Extrude edges only!]
[image: Move down along Z axis!]
[image: Go in top view!]
[image: Scale along normals]
[image: Move the vertices back up!]
[image: Like this!]
[image: Perfect outset!]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I have found is by inserting a face as normal.

Then double tab the <kbd>G</kbd> key and pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to slide your edge over the border.

Then you can delete the face or extrude it, depends on your demand.

https://media.giphy.com/media/llaNrdl1StxDxu127t/source.mp4

Comment: Thanks for the answer, useful trick. Could you please edit your question and [upload your image into the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) so it doesn't get lost? Here is how you can [post a GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site) in your answers.

Comment: Problem with this is it will change the angles of the edges unless the vertex normals meet very specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can get away with the distortion of the aspect ratio, you can just use the extrude (E-key) functionality.

Other than that  Mr Zak's comment is the best solution:

> scale the whole model / relevant part of model and inset the desired loop after.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to Extrude a Plane edges proportionally, and I couldn't find anything as I searched, so I came up with own solution and created a post. Apparently there was this post (which I couldn't find, because I searched with other words...) so my original post was deleted and I'm posting my method here (anyway, there is no solution to my problem in this post)

So I did it that way:

1. Extrude the whole plane.
2. Select edge faces and extrude along Normals. (hold `Alt` to get an even extrusion)
3. Delete the back face and edge, so that you again have only one plane as at the beginning.

[image][image][image][image]

**Also** I received a good answer from @GordonBrinkmann - to use built-in addon *Edit Mesh Tools* : "after selecting the outer edges of your plane go to the top menu and choose *Edge > Offset Edge > Extrude* "