# How to outset from edges/vertices?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges

I want to use outset on edges or vertices, as I have made a path with vertices and want to outset it. But it appears inset, with or without the outset option, does not work on edges or vertices. This is what I have, where the black lines are edges on a face:

[image]

And this is what I want to turn it into:

[image]

I've already tried Offset Edge Slide and Bevel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to Inset in the opposite direction (not Outset)?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/is-there-a-way-to-inset-in-the-opposite-direction-not-outset)

Comment: It works with edges?

Comment: Use the *Bevel* operator, `B` key

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried Bevel. This is the result: http://imgur.com/a/xowpT If you look back at the image in the original question, it isn't the same.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of would be just to add loopcuts and slide them to make them close to original loop. Note - quad geometry with appropriate edge flow needed for that.

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong keyboard shortcut, bevel is actually `Ctrl`+`B`. Add one additional loop or cut to the bevel from the operator properties, either in the *3D View Toolshelf* or by pressing `F6` after running Bevel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the bevel operator for this, by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> in mesh edit mode.

Add one additional loop or cut to the *Bevel* from the operator properties, either in the *3D View Toolshelf* or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> after running Bevel and increasing the number of cuts

[image: Bevel]