# Efficient method to extrude curbs

Tags: extrude

Very often I need to extrude a shape inwards or outwards to create a curb/wall or simply another edge loop. I move the verts around manually and it's a painful and long process. I'm looking for methods of extruding every vert by a set distance of it's parent vert.

This is what simply extruding and scaling does:

[image]

### This is what I need:

[image]

[image]

### Any fast way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Use the inset tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select the upper face, and press  <kbd>I</kbd>  to activate the inset tool.

Comment: Is there a way to extrude them outside not inside?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/is-there-a-way-to-inset-in-the-opposite-direction-not-outset