# Extrude a Plane edges proportionally

Tags: modeling, transforms, faces, extrude, proportional-editing

I want to extrude a plane proportionally like that. Something like inset function does, put outwards.
[image]

Here what I get.
[image]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You closed this question as duplicate linking to a question where the accepted answer links to an addon that is no longer available and there is no information how to get this to work today (with the new addon), the second answer will not give proper results in this case (and the link to the video is broken as well), and the third answer takes an unnecessary detour.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The last [answer by Rumen Belev](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/103205/19307) describes a native workflow without addons, that is identical to the one described here.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It is not identical, this is a different method and could be added to the other question as fourth option. But it is absolutely unnecessary work because Blender nowadays has the _Offset Edges_ > _Extrude_ function if you enable the built-in addon _Edit Mesh Tools_ which is much easier. Also Rumen's answer will not work well if the plane you want to extend is not orthogonal to the global or local coordinates (the answer given here by banana mate will work in this case by the way, another difference to Rumen's answer).

Comment: Yes, I see now that answer has a slightly different method, doesn't use modern tools and uses the *Scale Along Normals* instead of the *Extrude Along Normals* this one uses. Still the question is the same. Would you mind adding the workflow you described there to avoid scattering information all over. I'll ask Banana the same. Feel free to ping me for a free upvote

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Actually there was a newer question which also explained the more modern tool which I mention, unfortunately I couldn't find it because I would have linked to that and making this one a duplicate of it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Extrude the whole plane.
2. Select edge faces and extrude along Normals.
3. Delete the back face and edge, so that you again have only one plane as at the beginning.
4. Done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you want something like the _Inset_ tool: by default this is set to _Offset Even_. If you want the same with your method, you need to hit `S` or hold `Alt` while extruding. Or you just enable the addon _Edit Mesh Tools_ which comes with Blender and after selecting the outer edges of your plane go to the top menu and choose _Edge_ > _Offset Edge_ > _Extrude_, then you don't need all that extruding the whole plane, selecting edge face loop, extruding outwards, deleting back faces etc.

Comment: @Banana Mate You answer seems to add some modern improvements over existing answers over at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/is-there-a-way-to-inset-in-the-opposite-direction-not-outset. Could you copy paste this answer of yours there so we don't scatter valid answers everywhere. Feel free to ping me for an upvote

Comment: @Gordon I didnt understand what you meant by "hit S or hold Alt while extruding" - it didn't do anything...  But the addon _Edit Mesh Tools_ works just fine, thank you!

Comment: @bananamate You didn't do anything, right, that's what I said. When you do `Alt`+`E` to _Extrude Along Normals_ you have the option to hit `S` to toggle between even extrusion or not. You can also use `Alt`, but then you have to hold it while extruding to get an even extrusion. It is sometimes worth looking in the list of shortcuts in the tool menu bar while using a tool, there you can see which options it has. Or if you don't understand what this does, do the extrusion again with and without enabling _Even_ and just see the difference.

Comment: @Gordon Okay now I see! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Duarte I copied my answer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/is-there-a-way-to-inset-in-the-opposite-direction-not-outset/309783#309783